# Как передать данные с типом Int, в PropertyChangedEventArgs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Делаю приложение в котором можно выбирать мелодию, настраивать громкость и ставить таймер на отключение компьютера, всё это с помощью MVVM, мне нужно передать данные из слайдера, с типом Int, но в привязке к событию, должен быть тип string, заранее извиняюсь, если это глупый вопрос, но гуглил я долго. Подскажите как вообще организовать всё это дело, пишу в WPF впервые, и паттерном MVVM до этого не пользовался, но вот решил изучить[image: Моя модель]

Comment: непонятно, как вы [гуглили](https://www.google.com/search?q=propertychangedeventargs)? [Первая ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs?view=netframework-4.8) говорит, что конструктор принимает только строку- `PropertyChangedEventArgs(String)`, [вторая ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034840/handling-onpropertychanged) содержит полный ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: А если переключить [поисковик на русский язык](https://www.google.com/search?q=propertychangedeventargs&tbs=lr:lang_1ru&lr=lang_ru), то во второй же ссылке [документация на русском](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) с примерами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SoundValue));
```

Расписывать каждое свойство может быть утомительно, так что рекомендую обратить внимание на [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged).